# Assert_called_once_with need to check if the instances in the call are with the same info

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I'm trying to use assert_called_once_with from unittest.mock https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_once_with

But I want to check if 2 instances of objects have been passed with te correct attributes.

So inside the class I overrided the `__eq__` func:

```py
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (
            self.id == other.id
            and self.users == other.users
        )
```

And in the code I used like this

```py
        mock_add_user.assert_called_once_with(context_fix, expected_user_obj1, expected_user_obj2, users)
```

But I keep getting an error and the teste keeps comparing the repr of the instance, like this

```
<app.domain.model.load_md.Load object at 0x10cb7d7d0>
```

```py
E           AssertionError: Expected call: add_user(<app.infrastructure.context.Context object at 0x10cb7da50>, <app.domain.model.load_md.Load object at 0x10cb7d7d0>, <app.domain.model.load_md.Load object at 0x10cb7d550>, [1, 2, 3, 2])
E           Actual call: add_user(<app.infrastructure.context.Context object at 0x10cb7da50>, <app.domain.model.load_md.Load object at 0x10ca7f5d0>, <app.domain.model.load_md.Load object at 0x10cd1e650>, [1, 2, 3, 2])
```

I really need a way to assert if an instance of a object has being passed as an parameter of the function with the correct attributes filled.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use the [call_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) attribute of the mock object:

```py
from unittest.mock import ANY, Mock

class Foo:
    pass

def call(add_user):
    f = Foo()
    add_user(f)

def test_is_instance():
    mock_add_user = Mock()

    call(mock_add_user)

    # expected = Foo()
    # mock_add_user.assert_called_once_with(expected) # This would fail
    mock_add_user.assert_called_once_with(ANY)
    assert isinstance(mock_add_user.call_args.args[0], Foo)
```

Here is a slightly more complex example with `args` and `kwargs` assertions:

```py
from unittest.mock import ANY, Mock

class Foo:
    pass

class Bar:
    pass

def call(add_user):
    f = Foo()
    b = Bar()
    add_user(f, bar=b)

def test_is_instance():
    mock_add_user = Mock()

    call(mock_add_user)

    mock_add_user.assert_called_once_with(ANY, bar=ANY)
    assert isinstance(mock_add_user.call_args.args[0], Foo)
    assert isinstance(mock_add_user.call_args.kwargs["bar"], Bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need check only the instance type, you could check how to do with Foo object in example.
But if you need to compare all property values from object, you could check how to do with Bar object in example.

Example:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock
from dataclasses import dataclass


class Foo:
    def __eq__(self, __value: object) -> bool:
        if isinstance(__value, Foo):  # if you just need to check the instance type
            return True
        return False


@dataclass
class Bar:
    param_1: int
    param_2: str


def call_to_foo(add_user):
    f = Foo()
    add_user(f)


def call_to_bar(add_user):
    b = Bar(param_1=500, param_2="hello world")
    add_user(b)


def test_to_foo():
    mock_add_user = Mock()
    call_to_foo(mock_add_user)
    expected_foo = Foo()
    mock_add_user.assert_called_once_with(expected_foo)


def test_to_bar():
    mock_add_user = Mock()

    call_to_bar(mock_add_user)

    expected_bar = Bar(param_1=500, param_2="hello world")
    unexpected_bar = Bar(param_1=400, param_2="NOT hello world")
    mock_add_user.assert_called_once_with(expected_bar)
    mock_add_user.assert_called_once_with(unexpected_bar)  # THIS WILL FAIL
```